# A sufficient and necessary condition for $A\cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Find a sufficient and necessary condition for $A\cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$.

Here's my attempt:

For A ∪ (B ∩ C), I got X∈A or X∈B and X∈C. Now, for (A ∪ B) ∩ C, I got x∈A or x∈B and x∈C.

Therefore, I conclude that A∩C ≠ Ø

After that, do I have to prove the equality  **A ∪ (B ∩ C) = (A ∪ B) ∩ C**  by double inclusion or what I've done its sufficient (finding the condition A∩C ≠ Ø) ?

Comment: Do **not** delete and repost [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142647).

Comment: Thanks for deleting one of your duplicates. I've edited your work from that one into this one.

Comment: No problem @user21820. Thanks for the editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: If $A\subset C$ then $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap C$.

Proof: This is "obvious", since $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap C$.

Claim: If $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap C$ then $A\subset C$.

Proof: Suppose that $A\not\subset C$. Then the Left Hand Side (LHS) of our equality is also not a subset of $C$, but the Right Hand Side (RHS) is, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Just Draw A Venn Diagram (tm).

Shade in the bit that is the left-hand side, and shade in the bit that is the right-hand side. What's the minimal condition you need to impose to ensure that the shaded areas are actually the same?